# Get & Transform vs Conditional Format

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting, get-transform

I am trying to use `conditional formatting` on the output of a `Get & Transform` query.  (Office 365/Excel 2016 32 bit; Windows 10 Pro 64 bit).

However, when the query is refreshed, instead of the Conditional Formatting merely being extended/contracted to affect the resized column, it gets fubar'd as shown below.

I know I can obtain the desired output in a variety of ways, including VBA, and I do not need assistance in developing other methods.

Am I overlooking something either in the UI, or perhaps some method I could implement in the `Advanced Editor` to accomplish the normal extension of CF one would see if one just added a line to the table?

To reproduce the problem:

## Base Data

[image]

Use `Get & Transform` to unpivot columns 2-4, and remove the Attribute column

[image]

Conditional format to hide all except the first unique entry in column A1

[image]

## -->

[image]

Add another row to the original data table:

[image]

Update the query.

Note that the display and the CF "applies to" are messed up, and an extra CF condition is added

[image]

Is there anything I can do within the Query, or within Excel, to keep this from happening?  Or do I have to edit the conditional formatting (vba or manual)? (Or use a different solution to develop the output).

I have tried defining the `applies to` range using the structured reference, or using a dynamic name range. but that did not work. The `applies to` gets changed to an absolute reference, and develops the same changes as noted above when the Query is refreshed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work for me (but I literally just learned you could even do this with data by reading your post, so *thank you*!).

Set your conditional formatting calculation to

`=COUNTIF($A$2:$A2,$A2)>1`

and apply it to `=$A$2:$A$4`.

As an added bonus, every time I refreshed my data after updating the original table, my *Applies to* under the conditional formatting rule expanded the range down.

Comment: Excellent.  I wonder why this formula adjusts properly, and the other doesn't.  Oh, and with your formula, the `applies to:` can be limited to the range of the query result at the time.  So, for the first example in my question, `Applies to:` could be the same as I show `$A$2:$A$4`, and it will still expand/contract with the used range.

Comment: Exactly! I'm glad you pointed that out. I realized it while testing the formula and forgot to change it while I was typing my answer. Thanks for that! As to why it adjusts, I guess it's similar to when you insert a row that a conditional format crosses; the CF range expands to adjust for the new area.

Comment: My question isn't why your formula adjusts properly, it is why the simpler one does not adjust properly.

Comment: Oh. Sorry about that. It could be because the *Applies to* formula only covered the existing range. I've personally always had to go at least one row farther to get my formatting to continue on appropriately, but there could be more to it in this scenario.

Comment: No, because using A2:A4 worked above with your formula. And that was the existing range. BTW, your formula can/should be simplified to `=COUNTIF($A$2:$A2,$A2)>1`.  I suggest you edit your answer for both the applied range and the revised formula, if you agree.

Comment: It's been updated. Thanks. Updating it as suggested will help improve its performance.